Keep an element sticky when it reaches to the top and maintain original position when it scrolls down
I have a use case where I have a bunch of divs/text within a parent div. I want a certain element to be sticky to the top when that element reaches the top and it should get back to the original position when scrolled up again.
Please advice.
This is my code.
import { useRef, useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { _ } from "lodash";
import "./ScrollAwareDiv.css";

export const ScrollAwareDiv = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();
  const redDivRef = useRef();
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);
  const [isFixed, setIsFixed] = useState(false);

  const onScroll = useCallback(() => {
    if (myRef.current) {
      const { top } = redDivRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      const parentTop = myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      setScrollTop(myRef.current.scrollTop);

      if (top <= parentTop && !isFixed) {
        setIsFixed(true);
      } else if (top > parentTop && isFixed) {
        setIsFixed(false);
      }
    }
  }, [setScrollTop, isFixed]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const div = myRef.current;
    if (div) {
      div.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      return () => div.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    }
  }, [onScroll]);

  return (
    <div ref={myRef} className="scrollDiv">
      {_.times(15, (index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a
          scrollable react component. ScrollTop is {scrollTop}
        </p>
      ))}
      <div ref={redDivRef} className={isFixed ? "fixedDiv" : "normalDiv"}>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>
          RED RED RED. This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position
          within a scrollable react component.
        </p>
      </div>
      {_.times(15, (index) => (
        <p key={index}>
          This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a
          scrollable react component. ScrollTop is {scrollTop}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

This is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-dawn-k7kwxv?file=%2Fsrc%2FScrollAwareDiv.css%3A7%2C1
